React redux action dispatch fails when using separate webpack component bundle
I'm trying to create application that uses redux but uses a separately built webpack component bundle that also uses redux. However using redux in the component bundle always causes these errors in console:
bundle.js:2 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

react.development.js:1618 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1618:1)
    at bundle.js:2:1
    at r (bundle.js:2:1)
    at w (bundle.js:2:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:15486:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20103:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21626:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)

This is the configuration & code for EventReceiver component library:
package.json:
{
    "name": "eventreceiver",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --mode production"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^18.3.1",
        "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
        "react-redux": "^9.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
        "webpack": "^5.94.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
    }
}

webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    globalObject: 'this',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'], // Transpile ES6+ and JSX
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};

src\app.js:
import EventReceiver from './EventReceiver.js';

export { EventReceiver };

src\EventReceiver.js:
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function EventReceiver() {
  const accessed = useSelector((state) => state.event.accessed);

  return (
    <div>
      {accessed ? <p>got event</p> : <p>wait event</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default EventReceiver;

And this is what the application that uses EventReceiver library looks like:
package.json:
{
  "name": "redux-example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "EventReceiver": "file:../eventreceiver",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

src\App.js:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { applicationAccessed } from './store';
import { EventReceiver } from 'EventReceiver';

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(applicationAccessed());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <EventReceiver />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

src\index.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);

src\store.js:
import { configureStore, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const eventSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'event',
  initialState: { accessed: false },
  reducers: {
    applicationAccessed: (state) => {
      state.accessed = true;
    },
  },
});

export const { applicationAccessed } = eventSlice.actions;

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    event: eventSlice.reducer,
  },
});

export default store;

EventReceiver works if i embed it in application project instead of referring external library. I suspect that the problem is that i have more than one copy of React in the same app, however i have tried all the advices to prevent this but can't figure out what is wrong with the configuration. This is "npm ls react" output from application folder:
redux-example@0.1.0 C:\reduxtest\redux-example
├─┬ @reduxjs/toolkit@2.2.7
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped
├─┬ EventReceiver@npm:eventreceiver@1.0.0 -> .\..\eventreceiver
│ ├─┬ react-dom@18.3.1
│ │ └── react@18.3.1 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-redux@9.1.2
│ │ ├── react@18.3.1 deduped
│ │ └─┬ use-sync-external-store@1.2.2
│ │   └── react@18.3.1 deduped
│ └── react@18.3.1
├─┬ react-dom@18.3.1
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped
├─┬ react-redux@9.1.2
│ ├── react@18.3.1 deduped
│ └─┬ use-sync-external-store@1.2.2
│   └── react@18.3.1 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped
└── react@18.3.1

It has react@18.3.1 twice even though i have configured webpack so it shouldn't come from component library. Is the problem here or something totally else?
